# Application-defined or object-defined error when inserting a formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, runtime-error

The following formula works great when I directly add it in excel, but when I add it to VBA I get a Run Time error: Application-defined or object-defined error.

This is the Formula I am inserting into the macro:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP([[#This Row],[MATERIAL]],material!A$3:D$114,3)"
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
TableName = ActiveSheet.Previous.Name & "_Spider"

Range(TableName & "[RAWMATERIAL LENGTH]").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP([[#This Row],[MATERIAL]],material!A$3:D$114,3)"
```

Comment: Try using the macro recorder, I think that your syntax around `[[#This Row],[MATERIAL]]` is incorrect. The macro recorder should provide a suitable R1C1 formula to work with.

Comment: Use `Debug.Print` to output the formula to the Immediate pane in the VBE, and check it's what you're expecting. Copy/paste from there to the worksheet and check it's accepted. As @SamWard notes, your formula format looks wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that when you set the formula with `.FormulaR1C1` ([msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823188.aspx)), you have to refer to cells by row and column numbers (for example `=SQRT(R2C5)`).  You should try using `.Formula` ([msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx)) instead.